# Reverse for 'equipment_categories' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['equipments/equipment_categories/$']

Tags: python, django, sorting

I am trying to make a website that sorts equipment based on their category and i am getting the reverse match error when i link the urls on the webpage. Please i need advice on how i can properly pull this off. Thanks in advance.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'equipments_catalogue'

urlpatterns = [
    path('equipment_list/', views.EquipmentListView.as_view(), name='equipment_list'),
    path('equipment_categories/', views.EquipmentCategoryView.as_view(), 
        name='equipment_categories'),
    path('equipment_by_category/<str:cats>/', views.EquipmentListByCategory, 
        name='equipment_by_category')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from . import models

# Create your views here.

class EquipmentCategoryView(ListView):
    model = models.Category
    template_name = 'equipment_categories.html'

def EquipmentListByCategory(request, cats):
    equipment_category = models.Equipment.objects.filter(category=cats)
    return render(request, 'equipment_by_category.html', {'cats': cats , 'equipment_category': 
        equipment_category})

class EquipmentListView(ListView):
    model = models.Equipment
    template_name = 'equipment_list.html'
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to JPI Equipment Categories Page</h1>
    {% for category in object_list %}
        <a href="{% url 'equipments_catalogue:equipment_categories' equipment_by_category.category 
        %}">{{ category.name }}</a><br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling it wrong. The correct way to call it is {% url '<app_name>:<url_name>'  %}

Your app name is `equipments_catalogue`, your url name is `equipment_by_category`, not `equipment_categories`, which is correct, and the argument you should be passing should be a string, something like `category.name`:

```
{% url 'equipments_catalogue:equipment_by_category' category.name %}
```